# C# for Priority Line System (Queue) & network communication between

Tags: c#, node.js, rest, websocket

I started designing a program for Priority Line System (Queue Management for office desks) for usage in the company I work for because the current system is too old and doesn't have the functionality we need. The biggest obstacle is the best way for all the different systems to communicate with each other and the ability to reuse code on multiple platforms (Windows, Linux, Android & IOS). I have some experience with C# with .NET but not with .NET Core. Also, the communication in most of the parts of the system should be bi-directional.

My first thought was to use JSON and WebSockets. Then due to the usage of devices that can use web capabilities (TV for display, mobile apps with hybrid apps for local or remote), I thought that it will better to use RestApi or NodeJS.

So the main question is what is the best way to achieve communication between server and clients that is future proof and compatible with all the different systems.

The software will have the following functionality:
Application Server (Tracking of client requests for a ticket & agent requests for next ticket on hold. Also the ability to configure multiple Queues for multi-office & multi-brands).
IoT Client (For simple stand with a simple button & thermal printer)
Mobile Client (For stands with windows or android tablets & thermal printer)
Android TV View-App (For displaying Tickets in Queue & what desk to attend the next number)
Pc Desk Panel (Call Button for next in Queue, Display for Tickets in Queue, Count for completed Tickets)
Mobile App for remote Queue (The ability to reserve a ticket online and see the estimated time of service)

Comment: Anything involving "the best way" is at risk of being opinion based. If your solution is purely client to server, RestApi or gRPC would be good alternatives. If you need peer to peer you could consider some kind of message bus. As far as I know, NodeJS is a back end environment, not a networking protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am reading some examples of how to use RestApi right now. As for the mention of NodeJS, is thought to be a part of a solution only for Mobile Devices that use Android or IOS.